# How do I make AppBarLayout 25% of screen whilst it's in a CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have an `AppBarLayout` that I want to be 25% of the screen. If I was doing this without `Coordinator layout`, and `ConstraintLayout` I could simply use a `Guideline` with 25%, however the parent layout is a Coordinator so I'm not sure what to do here. I want to do it without setting a height in DP such as `150dp` and doing it in pure XML.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragprofile_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_app_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/concert_one"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tablayout"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/colorWhite60PercentOpacity" />


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any possible way to do this in XML without breaking some functionality of the `AppBarLayout`

But you can achieve the desired result programmatically

```
val appbar: AppBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.fragprofile_app_bar)
val lp = appbar.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
lp.height = (resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.25).toInt()
```